# How to integrate UIActivityViewController with SwiftUI's ScrollView?

Tags: swift, uikit, swiftui

In a project I have a `ScrollView` surrounding a `VStack` of items which each have a button to trigger the Activity View via the `UIActivityViewController`, but the Activity View doesn't appear.

I've reduced the project to the following code, which successfully displays the Activity View, but when I uncomment the `ScrollView`, the Activity View no longer appears when pressing the `"Open Activity View"` button.

Thanks!

```swift
import SwiftUI

class UIActivityViewControllerHost: UIViewController {
    var url: String = ""
    var completionWithItemsHandler: UIActivityViewController.CompletionWithItemsHandler? = nil

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let vc = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: [NSURL(string: url)!],
            applicationActivities: nil
        )
        vc.completionWithItemsHandler = completionWithItemsHandler
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }
}

struct ActivityView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var url: String
    @Binding var showing: Bool

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIActivityViewControllerHost {
        let result = UIActivityViewControllerHost()
        result.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activityType, completed, returnedItems, error) in
            self.showing = false
        }
        return result
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIActivityViewControllerHost, context: Context) {
        uiViewController.url = url
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSheet = false

    var body: some View {
//        ScrollView {
        Group {
            Button(action: {
                self.showSheet.toggle()
              }) {
                  Text("Open Activity View")
              }
            if showSheet {
                ActivityView(url: "https://www.wikipedia.org", showing: $showSheet)
                    .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
            }
        }
//    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the approach that works (tested with Xcode 11.2/iOS 13.2)... The extra wrapper host controller is not needed, and it is better to use native SwiftUI instruments for presentation.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ActivityView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var url: String
    @Binding var showing: Bool

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIActivityViewController {
        let vc = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: [NSURL(string: url)!],
            applicationActivities: nil
        )
        vc.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activityType, completed, returnedItems, error) in
            self.showing = false
        }
        return vc
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIActivityViewController, context: Context) {
    }
}

struct TestUIActivityView: View {
    @State var showSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
        Group {
            Button(action: {
                self.showSheet.toggle()
              }) {
                  Text("Open Activity View")
              }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                ActivityView(url: "https://www.wikipedia.org", showing: self.$showSheet)
            }
        }
    }
    }
}

struct TestUIActivityView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestUIActivityView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know how to put in the native variation. See also the following questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56700752/8642838
Your solution causes the sheet to run across the entire display