# UIButton in SwiftUI Catalyst Mac app doesn't work when clicked second time

Tags: swiftui, uibutton, uikit, uiactivityviewcontroller, mac-catalyst

Here's the code I have:

```swift
private struct ShareButton: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIButton {
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [URL(string: "https://www.apple.com/")!], applicationActivities: nil)
        let action = UIAction(title: "Share") { _ in UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?.rootViewController?.present(activityViewController, animated: false) }
        let button = UIButton(primaryAction: action)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = button
        return button
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIButton, context: Context) { }
}
```

Basically it's creating a `UIButton` with a `UIAction`, inside which there's a `UIActivityViewController` that set `sourceView` for the share menu to be the `UIButton`.

Here's a demo of the issue:
[image]

The `UIButton` is created when the SwiftUI view is created, and set as the `sourceView`. My guess is that the issue occur because the `UIButton` is somehow destroyed and recreated due to some SwiftUI mechanism? I can be entirely wrong though. Anyway to solve this?

Or any other way to do share button in a SwiftUI Catalyst Mac app?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59433735/12299030?

Answer (score 0):

"Or any other way to do share button in a SwiftUI Catalyst Mac app?"

You could try this approach, using the extension from:
[How to get rid of message " 'windows' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use UIWindowScene.windows on a relevant window scene instead" with AdMob banner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69650504/how-to-get-rid-of-message-windows-was-deprecated-in-ios-15-0-use-uiwindowsc)

```
public extension UIApplication {
    func currentUIWindow() -> UIWindow? {
        let connectedScenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            .filter({
                $0.activationState == .foregroundActive})
            .compactMap({$0 as? UIWindowScene})

        let window = connectedScenes.first?
            .windows
            .first { $0.isKeyWindow }

        return window

    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let holaTxt = "Hola  "
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            let AV = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [holaTxt], applicationActivities: nil)
            UIApplication.shared.currentUIWindow()?.rootViewController?.present(AV, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }) {
            Text("Share")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good approach to circumvent the deprecation, but it doesn't solve the issue of `sourceView` being gone for me

Comment: what is `sourceView`?

Answer (score 0):

Found an elegant solution for creating a share button in a SwiftUI Catalyst Mac app (in fact, all SwiftUI app), see https://github.com/SwiftUI-Plus/ActivityView

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you must [disclose your affiliation in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: @Tyler2P wdym? that's not my content