# How do I add a scroll view to a particular part of the screen in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, view, scroll, swiftui

I want to add a View like this.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: See question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56700752/swiftui-half-modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `SliverOverCard`

Here is a link to a github project

https://github.com/moifort/swiftUI-slide-over-card