# Show bottom sheet after button press swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, bottom-sheet

I'm trying to add to my app bottom sheet with responsive height which I can set programmatically. For this purpose I'm trying to use [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVBjgFHaysY). Here is code of my view controller:

```
struct SecondView: View {
    @State var cardShown = false
    @State var cardDismissal = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            cardShown.toggle()
            cardDismissal.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("Show card")
                .bold()
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .background(Color.red)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
        }
        
        BottomCard(cardShown: $cardShown, cardDismissal: $cardDismissal) {
            CardContent()
        }
    }
}

struct CardContent:View{
    var body: some View{
        Text("some text")
    }
}

struct BottomCard<Content:View>:View{
    @Binding var cardShown:Bool
    @Binding var cardDismissal:Bool
    let content:Content
    
    init(cardShown:Binding<Bool> , cardDismissal:Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content){
        _cardShown = cardShown
        _cardDismissal = cardDismissal
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View{
        ZStack{
            //Dimmed
            GeometryReader{ _ in
                EmptyView()
            }
            .background(Color.red.opacity(0.2))
            .opacity(cardShown ? 1 : 0)
            .animation(.easeIn)
            .onTapGesture {
                cardShown.toggle()
            }
            
            // Card
            VStack{
                Spacer()
                
                VStack{
                    content
                }
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}
```

but after pressing the button I don't see any pushed bottom menu. I checked and it seems that I have similar code to this video but on the video bottom sheet appears. Maybe I missed something important for menu showing. The main purpose is to show bottom menu with responsive height which will wrap elements and will be able to change menu height. I tried to use `.sheet()` but this element has stable height as I see. I know that from the ios 15+ we will have some solutions for this problem but I would like to create something more stable and convenient :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI - Half modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56700752/swiftui-half-modal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## iOS 16

We can have native SwiftUI resizable sheet (like UIKit). This is possible with the new `.presentationDetents()` modifier.

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showBudget) {
    BudgetView()
        .presentationDetents([.height(250), .medium])
        .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
}
```

#### Demo:

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 0):

| This is what I got when running your code | I got this after some adjustments to bottom card |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

```
struct BottomCard<Content:View>:View{
    @Binding var cardShown:Bool
    @Binding var cardDismissal:Bool
    let content:Content

    init(cardShown:Binding<Bool> , cardDismissal:Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content){
        _cardShown = cardShown
        _cardDismissal = cardDismissal
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View{
        ZStack{
            //Dimmed
            GeometryReader{ _ in
                EmptyView()
            }
            .background(Color.red.opacity(0.2))
            .animation(.easeIn)
            .onTapGesture {
                cardShown.toggle()
            }

            // Card
            VStack{
                Spacer()

                VStack{
                    content
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .opacity(cardShown ? 1 : 0)
    }
}
```

So you just need to set the height!

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is to have a card that only exists when there is a certain standard met.
If you want to push up a card from the bottom then you can make a view of a card and put it at the bottom of a Zstack view using a geometry reader and then make a button that only allows for that card to exist when the button is pressed INSTEAD of trying to hire it by changing its opacity. Also, make sure you move the dismissal button to the inside of the cad you have.

Heres an example you can try :

```
struct SecondView: View {
    @State var cardShown = false

     var body: some View {
      GeometryReader{
              ZStack {
                ZStack{
       // I would also suggest getting used to physically making your 
       //button and then giving them functionality using a "Gesture"
                 Text("Show Button")
                  .background(Rectangle())
                  .onTapGesture{
                 let animation = Animation.spring()
                   withAnimation(animation){
                     self.cardShown.toggle
                   }
                 }
               }
                ZStack {
                 if cardShown == true{
                   BottomCard(cardShown: $cardShown) {
                      CardContent()
                  }
               }
              // here you can change how far up the card comes after the button 
               //is pushed by changing the "0"
                .offset(cardShown == false ? geometry.size.height : 0)
               }
             }
           }
         }
       }
```

Also, you don't need to have a variable for the card being shown and a variable for the card being dismissed. Just have one "cardShown" variable and make it so that when it is TRUE the card is shown and when it is FALSE (after hitting the button on the card or hitting the initial button again.) the card goes away.

Answer (score 0):

## iOS 16.0+

iPadOS 16.0+

macOS 13.0+

Mac Catalyst 16.0+

tvOS 16.0+

watchOS 9.0+

---

Use `presentationDetents(_:)`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isBottomSheetVisible = false


    var body: some View {
        Button("View Settings") {
            isBottomSheetVisible = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isBottomSheetVisible) {
            Text("Bottom Sheet")
                .presentationDetents([.height(250), .medium])
                .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
        }
    }
}
```