# What is this view in SwiftUI called?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Can anyone tell me what this sort of expandable toolbar, containing sliders, is called? I'm still a beginner in development and can't seem to find this views name, or any place where to learn it.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: It is new thing in iOS, but you can easily make a custom one for yourself as well in SwiftUI. like this one: https://vm.tiktok.com/ZM8HFT9Pk/ I am developing it for myself need some more works to finished.

Answer (score 1):

It is a modal/half sheet/popover not available in SwiftUI as a pre-built `View`.

You can add the sliders, tab view and segmented picker per your requirements to the modal.

There are many way to implement it.

in iOS 15 Apple has provided `adaptiveSheetPresentationController` so it can be implemented using UIKit.

[SwiftUI - Half modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56700752/swiftui-half-modal/67994666#67994666)

Here is a [WWDC21](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10063) video too

There are other ways, the referenced question has many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

As @loren Epsom said, its a half sheet, and as its not pre built view in SwiftUI, I recommend using this framework, if the nature of your work allow 3rd party frameworks, [Partial Sheet](https://github.com/AndreaMiotto/PartialSheet)

[image]

The setup is pretty straight forward, for example you can use something like:

```
.partialSheet(isPresented: $isSheetShown) {
    //Add the SwiftUI view that you want to appear in the partial sheet.
}
```

Read the [How to Use](https://github.com/AndreaMiotto/PartialSheet#how-to-use)