# SwiftUI sheet showing full screen

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a large code base wherein I have a SwiftUI view and am trying to present a bottom sheet using the following code.

```
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentedSheet, content: {
            Rectangle().foregroundColor(.pink)
        })
```

For some reason it always shows full screen, and does not support drag down to close. Tested in iOS 13, 14, and 15. If I create a small test app and use the same code, it works correctly. I am not sure why in the larger code base it isn't working. Any ideas?

For the [SwiftUI - Half modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56700752/swiftui-half-modal) suggestion, I'm not sure how that helps my case per se. I want to do something simple, which is to get the `sheet` modifier to work correctly.

Comment: Check that, in the larger code, there is no extension to `View` that is changing the `.sheet()` modifier.

Comment: I don't think there is. How would that work exactly? By overriding the sheet function you mean?

Comment: When I run into these problems, I move the view up the view tree to find the place that is causing the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI - Half modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56700752/swiftui-half-modal)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @PylypDukhov tried moving it to the root of the view hierarchy but same problem.

Comment: You need to find the difference with a blank project, it can be anything. Remove all unrelated files from build/comment all unrelated code, remove dependencies, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out the problem. The `modalPresentationStyle` of `.pageSheet` was disabled using method swizzling. I have no idea why that is, but at least I know the answer now. Thanks for all the feedback.

Comment: Hey rubenz, any chance you can share the source code of the full screen sheet?

Comment: not sure I get you. Do you want this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/fullscreencover(ispresented:ondismiss:content:)?