# Is it possible to have a WKWebView open a web page which only occupies half the screen?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, swiftui, webkit

I am building an iOS app where part of the app is to be displayed as a Web View using WKWebView. Instead of opening the web page in a full screen, I want the WKWebView to cover only half the screen (like a floating native UI element) with the app in the background.

For reference, I want an experience something like https://social.msdn.microsoft.com//Forums/getfile/1679719 (image obtained from Google image search).

**Is it possible to achieve this using WKWebView?**

Side note: I was considering SFSafariViewController first and looks like it is not possible (at least not recommended) to have SFSafariViewController in this sort of setup.

I was not able to clearly confirm from the WKWebView documentation [1] or other Apple sources [2] if this was supported. As per [2],

> You can present a full or partial view of web content directly in your app ...

But it was not clear if this is the same as the experience I was trying to build

References:

[1] https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview

[2] https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=trjs0tcd

Comment: AFAIK, WKWebView is just like other UIView and can be any size. It can be a subview of another UIView which also can be any size. So you can have a Modal small view which include a WKWebView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to cover only have the screen with a WKWebView.

Check [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56700752/swiftui-half-modal) for SwiftUI possibilities.

And here is a quick UIKit example:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

     var webView: WKWebView!
     let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         view.backgroundColor = .red
         webView = WKWebView()
         webView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.height / 2, width: 
         view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height / 2)
         view .addSubview(webView)
         webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The link to the Swift UI answer was also super helpful! This answers my question.