# SwiftUI: Popup appear doesn't animate correct and glitching view behind

Tags: animation, swiftui, popup

I'm trying to create popup in SwiftUI and faced some problems. Some of them like a different `.transition` on the same `View` solved by tips from SO, but some still hard to resolve.

There are few problems in code example:

1. Popup view animate incorrect when you first time call it. It's just appear but not coming from the bottom
2. It seems like two types of `.transition` applying to popup, but it should be one to each part of it
3. Data on the back View start to glitching when popup appears and disappears
4. And finally popup doesn't come from the bottom and disappears before coming to the edge

**Code example**

```
struct SOAnimation: View {
    @State var selectedImage = "camera.filters"
    @State var showPopup = false
    @State var showView = true
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            VStack {
                Text("Image").font(.largeTitle).fontWeight(.bold)
                ZStack {
                    Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 81, height: 81)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.blue.opacity(0.2))
                    Image(systemName: selectedImage)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                } .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        showPopup = true
                    }
                }
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    ForEach(1..<25) { _ in
                        Text(UUID().uuidString)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            if showPopup { Popup(selectedImage: $selectedImage, showPopup: $showPopup)}
        }
    }
}

struct Popup: View {
    @Binding var selectedImage: String
    @Binding var showPopup: Bool
    private let columns: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: .init(.flexible()), count: 4)
    private let images = ["camera.filters", "seal", "circle", "oval", "app", "diamond", "octagon", "play", "pause", "forward", "goforward", "wave.3.forward", "skew"]
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if showPopup { // Logic for different types of transition
                Color.black.opacity(0.5)
                    .onTapGesture { withAnimation(.spring()) { showPopup = false }}
                    .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .all)
                    .transition(.opacity)
            }
            if showPopup { // Logic for different types of transition
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(images, id: \.self) { image in
                        Image(systemName: image)
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                selectedImage = image
                                withAnimation(.spring()) { showPopup = false }
                            }
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                .onTapGesture {}
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Code example result:**

[image]

**Expected result:**

[image]

Comment: what iOS are you targetting?

Comment: @Timmy targeting iOS 15

Comment: Well, in that case why not use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67994666/13278922 which is centered around the native half sheet that **Apple** created

Answer (score 0):

If I'm guessing, the undefined behavior comes from the `LazyVGrid`, you can achieve the same layout with `VStacks` and `HStacks`.

I also think it would be better to create a viewModifier and an extension for the popup instead of using `ZStack`'s. I followed this [article](https://www.artemnovichkov.com/blog/custom-popups-in-swiftui) and use a similar popup in my app without any problems.