# How to present half screen view as a modal?

Tags: swiftui, presentation

Using **iOS 15**, how would I do this? Modifying a views height and presenting it in a sheet makes no difference.

```
.onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self) { value in
   size = value
}
.frame(height: size.height)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56700752/swiftui-half-modal/67994666#67994666