How to remove the shadow when using UISheetPresentationController?
I'm currently writing a custom bottom sheet to use in SwiftUI which uses UISheetPresentationController. I have created a struct that conforms to UIViewRepresentable. In the updateUIView method, I'm wrapping a SwiftUI view in a UIHostingController then presenting the view controller as a sheet.
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
    let viewController = UIViewController()
    
    let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: content)

    viewController.addChild(hostingController)
    viewController.view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
    
    hostingController.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    viewController.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.topAnchor, constant: 20),
        hostingController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
        hostingController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
        hostingController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
    ])
    
    hostingController.didMove(toParent: viewController)

    if let sheetController = viewController.presentationController as? UISheetPresentationController {
        sheetController.detents = detents
        sheetController.largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier = .large
        sheetController.prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge = false
        sheetController.prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight = true
        sheetController.widthFollowsPreferredContentSizeWhenEdgeAttached = true
    }
    
    viewController.presentationController?.delegate = context.coordinator
    
    if isPresented {
        uiView.window?.rootViewController?.present(viewController, animated: true)
    } else {
        uiView.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}

I have modified the code so that the sheet has a clear background so that the SwiftUI view looks like it's floating.

However, when you start to swipe down on the sheet you start to see the shadow from the sheet.

As you can see there is a clear dividing line where there is an extra shadow onto of the dimmed background.
I have looked through the view hierarchy and it appears not to be related to the hosting controller or the view controller. I have tried adjusting properties such as layer.shadowColor on the sheetController but most of those properties are nil. Does anyone know how to remove the shadow or any other suitable work around for it?
EDIT: The minimal reproducible example.
struct SheetPresentationForSwiftUI<Content>: UIViewRepresentable where Content: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    let onDismiss: (() -> Void)?
    let detents: [UISheetPresentationController.Detent]
    let content: Content
    
    init(
        _ isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
        onDismiss: (() -> Void)? = nil,
        detents: [UISheetPresentationController.Detent] = [.medium()],
        @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content
    ) {
        self._isPresented = isPresented
        self.onDismiss = onDismiss
        self.detents = detents
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        let viewController = UIViewController()
        
        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: content)

        viewController.addChild(hostingController)
        viewController.view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
        
        hostingController.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        viewController.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.topAnchor),
            hostingController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.leadingAnchor),
            hostingController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.trailingAnchor),
            hostingController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        
        hostingController.didMove(toParent: viewController)
        hostingController.view.sizeToFit()

        if let sheetController = viewController.presentationController as? UISheetPresentationController {
            sheetController.detents = [.medium()]
            sheetController.largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier = .large
            sheetController.prefersGrabberVisible = true
            sheetController.prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge = false
            sheetController.prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight = true
            sheetController.widthFollowsPreferredContentSizeWhenEdgeAttached = true
        }
        
        viewController.presentationController?.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        if isPresented {
            uiView.window?.rootViewController?.present(viewController, animated: true)
        } else {
            uiView.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(isPresented: $isPresented, onDismiss: onDismiss)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UISheetPresentationControllerDelegate {
        @Binding var isPresented: Bool
        let onDismiss: (() -> Void)?
        
        init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, onDismiss: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
            self._isPresented = isPresented
            self.onDismiss = onDismiss
        }
        
        func presentationControllerDidDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
            isPresented = false
            if let onDismiss = onDismiss {
                onDismiss()
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}

struct SheetWithDetentsViewModifier<SwiftUIContent>: ViewModifier where SwiftUIContent: View {
    
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    let onDismiss: (() -> Void)?
    let detents: [UISheetPresentationController.Detent]
    let swiftUIContent: SwiftUIContent
    
    init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, detents: [UISheetPresentationController.Detent] = [.medium()] , onDismiss: (() -> Void)? = nil, content: () -> SwiftUIContent) {
        self._isPresented = isPresented
        self.onDismiss = onDismiss
        self.swiftUIContent = content()
        self.detents = detents
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            SheetPresentationForSwiftUI($isPresented,onDismiss: onDismiss, detents: detents) {
                swiftUIContent
            }
            .fixedSize()
            content
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func sheetWithDetents<Content>(
        isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
        detents: [UISheetPresentationController.Detent] = [.medium()],
        onDismiss: (() -> Void)? = nil,
        content: @escaping () -> Content) -> some View where Content : View {
            modifier(
                SheetWithDetentsViewModifier(
                    isPresented: isPresented,
                    detents: detents,
                    onDismiss: onDismiss,
                    content: content)
            )
        }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @State var showSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Tap me")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        showSheet = true
                    }
            }
        }.sheetWithDetents(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            Text("Hello")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .padding()
                .background(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40)
                        .fill(Material.regularMaterial)
                        
                ).padding()
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    TestView()
}


Why do you need a UIViewControllerRepresentable? Almost all of the things a UISheetPresentationController can do can be done in SwiftUI, too.

SwiftUI's sheet goes edge to edge. I want padding around the entire sheet similar to the sheet shown when you connect AirPods. Also 'presentationBackground` is only available in iOS 16.4+

Okay, fair enough. Can you show a [mcve], and not just updateUIView? It shouldn't be too hard to produce some code that I can directly copy and paste into a new project and reproduce the issue.

I've added it now

You don’t need UIViewRepresentable if you are going to use the root anyway

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56700752/swiftui-half-modal/67994666#67994666
